# A toy example of the concurrent stack via atomic variables and CAS pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stack, atomic

I've written a toy example of the concurrent stack which has only three functions `push()`, `peek()`, and `length()`. I've used atomic variables for synchronization. Is there anything incorrect in terms of synchronization? Could you please review this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node<T>* next{};
    T val{};
    Node(const T& v) : val(v) {};
};

template <typename T>
class Stack {
    std::atomic<Node<T>*> top{};
    std::atomic<size_t> size{};
    public:
    void push(const T& data) {
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>(data);
        size_t length = size.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        node->next = top.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&top, &node->next, node, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
        while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&size, &length, size + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }
    Node<T>* peek() {
        return top.load();
    }
    size_t length() const {
        return size;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Runner {
    int cnt{};
    Stack<T>* ss{};
    public:
        Runner(const int n, Stack<T>* s) : cnt(n), ss(s) {}
        void operator()() {
            for(int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
                size_t size = ss->length();
                if(size >= cnt) {
                    return;
                }
                ss->push(i);
            }
        }
        Stack<T>* get_stack() const {
            return ss;
        }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads{};
    Stack<int>* s = new Stack<int>();
    int n = 10;
    Runner<int> r(n, s);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::move(std::thread(r)));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    Stack<int>* top = r.get_stack();
    Node<int>* head = top->peek();
    while(head) {
        std::cout << head->val << ", ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    size_t size = top->length();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's the possibility that your example will add more than 10 numbers to your stack.

Comment: So, probably I need to apply some sync mechanism in operator()() as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Naming

My immediate reaction is that without a `pop` (or something equivalent) it's not really a stack. Especially given the item below about exposing the implementation details, from a client's viewpoint it's really a linked list that supports only a couple of operations: adding nodes to the beginning, getting the length, and (by knowing the implementation) traversing the list.

#### Exposing Internal Details

As it stands now, it seems to rely on client code to realize that it's implemented as a linked-list, so access to elements other than the top require client code to use `peek` to get a pointer to the top element, and then traverse the nodes of the linked list to get to the rest of the elements.

#### Avoiding Race Conditions

I'd also question (to at least some degree) inclusion of `length` in the interface. In a multi-threaded environment, almost all possible uses of `length` are practically guaranteed to introduce race conditions--by the time you actually try to *use* a length you've read, the length may have changed, so you're using obsolete information.

It can (at least sort of) make some sense to use a `length` for things like logging, simply to give the user at least some notion of whether the stack is (for example) growing constantly (but in this case, that's pretty much a given, since you've omitted a `pop` from its interface).

#### Side Note

It's not immediately apparent whether you're thinking of `Runner` as part of the `Stack` itself, or an ancillary class you included to demonstrate/test the actual `Stack`. At least for now, I've treated it as ancillary, so it shows how the `Stack` is used, but I haven't really tried to review it in itself.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jerry Coffin's answer:

## Move `struct Node` into `class Stack`

A `Node` is just an implementation detail of a `Stack`, so move the declaration of the former into the latter. As a bonus you avoid having to repeat `<T>`. Here is how this looks:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
public:
    struct Node {
        Node* next{};
        T val{};
        Node(const T& v): val(v) {};
    };

private:
    std::atomic<Node*> top{};
    ...
};
```

While I agree with Jerry Coffin that you should have a proper `pop()` instead of a `peek()`, using the latter would now look like this:

```
Stack<int>::Node* head = top->peek();
```

Although you should just use `auto` here:

```
auto head = top->peek();
```

## Don't forget to clean up memory

I see `new` in your code but no `delete`. That means you have a memory leak. Normally I would recommend you use [`std::unique_ptr<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage memory, but since you are using atomic pointers, that doesn't work. So ensure you add destructors to `Node` and `Stack` so that the resources are cleaned up correctly.

And in `main()`, there is no reason to use `new` to create a new `Stack`, just declare it on... the stack:

```
Stack<int> s;
Runner<int> r(n, &s);
```

## Use `emplace_back()`

In the following line, the `move()` is unnecessary:

```
threads.push_back(std::move(std::thread(r)));
```

This is because `std::thread(r)` is a temporary, and thus the overload of [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) that takes an r-value reference will be chosen. However, even better is to use [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), as then you can simply write:

```
threads.emplace_back(r);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review and for your time.